# What to include in an RPM created from python packages

Tags: rhel, rpm, python

I'm looking to create a rpm for this [tarball](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentView?documentID=49237&showInfo=true) and couldn't figure out which files needed to be included in the package after the install. I am used to compiling some code and including the binary output; however, since this is all python and seems to use `distutils` to install everything is there even bin/executable to include in the package? I thought distutils just adds the module to the appropriate 3rd party python modules dir on the target machine.

If I use:

```
%install
make install DESTDIR=%{buildroot}
```

what would be the appropriate output to include in the rpm package, i.e., under `%files`?

I came across an already made .spec file [here](https://github.com/repoforge/rpms/blob/master/specs/cvs2svn/cvs2svn.spec) which which seemed to include the entire `/usr/bin` (`rpm --eval %{_bindir}` expands to `/usr/bin` on my machine) directory which seemed excessive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [package](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?package=cvs2svn&project=devel%3Atools%3Ascm%3Asvn) in the [openSUSE BuildService](http://build.opensuse.org). You can even try to build it for RHEL if you create your own project there (and add the appropriate repository).